# Force DispForm to open in current tab (not Dialog)

Tags: 2010, dialog, dispform

In SharePoint 2010 , the default is for DispForm, EditForm and NewForm.aspx to open in a dialog. I need to override this but I'm unsure how.

How can I open the List Item in the Current Window (as 2013 would) rather than in a Dialog / Popup?

I'm assuming that would mean removing this from the URL. Is that what's happening?

```
DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change this per list, then in your list, go to List Settings and then Advanced Settings, there is a section titled Dialogs, where you can change the setting "Launch forms in a dialog" to no.